# What could be delaying the printf output of my C program?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

A simplified version of my code is:

```
#include "externalstuff.h"
void main(){
    printf("Hello?");
    /* make calls to externalstuff
    ....
    */
}
```

I did not write `externalstuff.h`, so I'm not sure what is going on there exactly.

The calls to `externalstuff` take some time to execute. I would expect that `"Hello?"` would get printed, then I would have to wait for those external calls to finish, then my program would end. But what seems to be happening is that `"Hello?"` only gets printed right before my program ends, after a long wait for the `externalstuff`.

Is it possible that something in `externalstuff.h` is delaying this output? If so, how?

I'm using gcc in cygwin on Widnows 7.

Comment: The 'hold-up' is the fact that you don't add a newline to the end of the format string.  Output is line buffered by default; that means, output appears when a newline is generated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Buffering delays the output of your program. When you call `printf`, the output is stored in a buffer until one of three things happen:

- The length of internal buffer becomes insufficient for holding the output, or
- You call `fflush(stdout)` to initiate sending the buffer to console explicitly, or
- You print `'\n'` character, and the output is sent to console (as opposed to sending the output to a file).

If you don't like this behavior, and do not mind somewhat slower performance, you can call

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

to disable buffering.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. This has been bothering me for a while. Now I understand it.